# SoapException com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: mysql, web-services, soap

I have several WebMethods involving sql, when I call a method it sends a soapException involving the com.mysql.jdbc.driver

This is my connection method (it is not a web method but it is on the web service class along with the rest of the web methods)

```
    public Connection connect() throws Exception        
    {
        if (con == null)
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ProyectGameSmart","root","root");
        }
        return con;
}
```

This is one of the web methods that need to get a connection instance

```
    public int insert_publisher(String pub, String phone, String addr) throws Exception
{
    int ResultValue = 0;
    connect();
    query="INSERT INTO ProyectGameSmart.Publisher(Publisher,Phone,Address)VALUES('"+pub+"','"+phone+"','"+addr+"');";       
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultValue = pstmt.executeUpdate();
    return ResultValue;
}
```

Can anyone help me on how to implement a web service involving sql connection. I have only been able to find web services with simple math methods. I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat 7.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look in your server logs for the full stack trace of the exception thrown. The current problem you're experiencing has more to do with your database access code and nothing to do with the SOAP stack. All SOAP is doing right now is informing you that there is a problem in your DB access code. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is working locally, I mean without running as a web service. Then You have to put the correct version of the mysql JDBC driver in to your classpath of the web services server. Here Tomcat lib folder. That will solve th problem.